# Can you use Protractor in combination with PageFactory?

Tags: c#, protractor, pageobjects, protractor-net

Is it possible to use protractor with PageFactory/Pagobject pattern. On GitHub this question was asked before (https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/issues/5) and some changes were made in protractor to support the PageFactory pattern but for me it's not clear how to initialize the NgWebelements in the PageObject. At the moment I'm working with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you Can.
Check out the sample in the GitHub repository :
https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/tree/master/examples/Protractor.Samples/PageObjects

Comment: Thnx, it's what I was looking for.